# How to deselect shipping method in M2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, shipping-methods

On my checkout page I have Post(Online API) shipping method, in which I have many shipping points available, customer can choose whatever he want.

By default the first shipping point is selected, I want to remove this preselected thing and want customer to choose before placing the order.

Any tips??

I tried this https://www.magemonkeys.com/how-to-uncheck-default-shipping-method-magento-2/ but doesnt help

Answer (score 4):

Try following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': {
                'SR_MagentoCommunity/js/mixin/checkout-data-resolver-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/checkout-data-resolver-mixin.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method'
], function (selectShippingMethodAction) {
        'use strict';
        return function (target) {
            target.resolveShippingRates = function(ratesData) {
                selectShippingMethodAction(null);
            };

            return target;
        }
    }
);
```

***Clear browser js cache, remove pub/static if your magento mode is not developer. Clear cache.***

Comment: I am getting this `CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/TEST/Theme/nb_NO/Mgento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method.js'`

Comment: What is this 'frontend/TEST/Theme/nb_NO/Mgento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method.js'?

Comment: This is wrong path.

Comment: I added your code in custom module and after enabling your code, am getting 404 for select-shipping-method.js on checkout page

Comment: God knows how you add. This is working fine with fresh installation

Comment: @SohelRana I used this method to deslect & it is working fine, but I am facing issue that the checkout="true" still remains which keeps tick mark. I need to remove that?