# Magento2 need to remove checked="true" from shipping methods radio button even when 1 shipping method is available

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to remove checked="true" from shipping methods radio button even when 1 shipping method is available

How can I achieve this as magento2 by default adds check true when single shipping method

Comment: Please check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/275679/84221

Comment: i used that only & also added comment